# A project can have only one link to the same file

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am getting the following warning in Visual Studio 2017:

```
The file [filepath] could not be added to the project. 
There is already a link to [filepath]. 
A project cannot have more than one link to the same file.
```

I searched on SO but no related solution could find. I checked in .csproj file but only one link is there  and "location to copy" for the same file. What could be the fix for this? As only one link is added to the project but compiler is showing as more than one.

Comment: I am having the same issue in VS2022 with shared projects.